# How can I add non-column specific parameters to a C# table adapter?

Tags: .net, dataset, tableadapter

I'm using a TableAdapter for the first time and adding a custom query to it, and I'm getting stuck on adding some search parameters to my query, here's what I've got:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Orders
WHERE   (id_order = @id_order) OR
        (IsFor LIKE '%@word1%') OR
        (IsFor LIKE '%@word2%') OR
        (IsFrom LIKE '%@word1%') OR
        (IsFrom LIKE '%@word2%')
```

When I test execute the query, I'm prompted for id_order, but not word1 or word2.  I also tried adding these directly as parameters to the adapter and pass them in but they don't work.  Strangely, id_order continues to work, but the other values don't generate any matches.

My goal is to allow the user to type in first &/or last name and have it match any orders with that first &/or last name.

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need quotes or percent signs.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Orders
WHERE   (id_order = @id_order) OR
    (IsFor LIKE @word1) OR
    (IsFor LIKE @word2) OR
    (IsFrom LIKE @word1) OR
    (IsFrom LIKE @word2)
```

Comment: That was definitely half of it.

I still did need the % signs for a partial match, but instead of embedding them in the query, I added these to the parameters directly and voila, it worked.

Thanks!

Comment: My bad.  I thought the % was already there.  If you want to add them in the query, do IsFor LIKE '%' + @word1 + '%'